# perl delete hash items if not found in an array

Tags: arrays, perl, hash

I have the following hash:
`%{$data{$id}{$date}}`
that includes a large number of dates

and an array `@dates` that includes a subsection of dates found in the `%hash`.

What is the best way to loop through my `%hash` and delete all dates that are not found in `@dates` array? Once this is done I'd like the `%hash` to only have the values from `@array` dates.

I've tried 'delete unless exists' looking at keys after I created a hash from my `@dates` array but would get missing arguments error.

Comment: Please [edit] and show us the actual code you wrote that includes `delete unless exists` and the exact error message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as the dates in `@dates` are guaranteed to appear in the hash you can use `map`

```
%{ $data{$id} } = map { $_ => $data{$id}{$_} } @dates
```

Comment: Good alternative. `$data` is a reference to a hash so you need to write `$$data{$id}{$_}` instead of `$data{$id}{$_}`.

Comment: @blhsing: If `$data` is a hash reference then the OP's code is wrong, and I have no reason to assume so.

Comment: @blhsing: Even if you were correct, it would be best to write `$data->{$id}{$_}`

Comment: @borodin Thanks! This filtered out all the correct dates but I end up with undef hash for all but the last date. I'll work on debugging this.

Comment: You don't describe your data structure very carefull and I may have misunderstood it. If you add a dump of your hash into the question then it will help.

Answer (score 4):

You should loop through the keys of `%{$data{$id}}` instead.

```
my %dates = map {$_ => 1} @dates;
exists $dates{$_} or delete $data{$id}{$_} for keys %{$data{$id}};
```